# Redirecting to domains not found within code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, solr

I took over maintaining a CMS system.  The site is running on passenger and nginx and has a separate solr server.  I've made changes. For example, I disabled solr indexing because it had caused slowdown.

Users report that links within the site started to redirect to invalid domains.  The redirects seem to be to old domains that were used for testing.  I cannot reproduce any of these bugs and I cannot find any trace of these domains.

Does anyone have any advice for hunting down this type of bug?  Any places where links to old domains may appear and randomly cause people to be redirected?  Or any tools that may help?

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't be a big issue. Ask the user which links are wrong. You should be able to spot that on the view file.

A simple string search for a URL in you application code may not work because the they may be created dynamically with the aid of helper methods.

Comment: The issue is that I can't recreate the error.  They only pop up very rarely and I can never get the links reported to provide me with the wrong redirect.  I'll take a closer look through the view files though and see if I notice anything wrong.